# Update UI in Flutter from Websocket if App is in Background

Tags: android, flutter, websocket, flutter-dependencies, mobile-application

I am creating an Android application in Flutter. So basically, some part of my UI depends on the response I get from the WebSocket. Everything is working fine when the application is running in the foreground, but when the app is in the background I get responses from WebSocket but the UI is not changing.
What should I do such that the app's UI will change when it is in the background?

Here is the code for websocket:

```
WebSocketHelperService sockets = new WebSocketHelperService();

class WebSocketHelperService {
  WebSocketChannel _channel;
  ObserverList<Function> _listeners = new ObserverList<Function>();
  final streamController = StreamController.broadcast();

  Timer timer;

  wserror(err) async {
    print(new DateTime.now().toString() + " Connection error: $err");
    await reconnect();
  }

  reconnect() async {
    if (timer != null) {
      timer.cancel();
    }
    if (_channel != null) {
      print("Web socket have been disconnected");
      reset();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));
    }
    print(new DateTime.now().toString() + " Starting connection attempt...");
    _channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(webSocketUrl,
        pingInterval: Duration(seconds: 3));
    print(new DateTime.now().toString() + " Connection attempt completed.");
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3),
        (Timer t) async => await sockets.send(json.encode({"type": "cm-rp"})));
    _channel.stream.listen((data) {
      streamController.add(data);
      print(data);
    }, onDone: reconnect, onError: wserror, cancelOnError: false);
  }

  // Closes the WebSocket communication
  reset() {
    if (_channel != null) {
      if (_channel.sink != null) {
        _channel.sink.close();
      }
    }
  }

  // Sends a message to the server
  send(String message) async {
    if (_channel != null) {
      if (_channel.sink != null) {
        debugPrint(message);
        _channel.sink.add(message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how I am using websocket to change the UI:

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: sockets.streamController.stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      var snapBody = jsonDecode(snapshot.data);
    }
    return Text(
      snapshot.hasData ? snapBody['something'] : "Name"
    );
  }
);
```